# Synonym for 'idiomatically'

Tags: synonyms

What could be a good and appropriate synonym for idiomatically? I want to use it in phrase " both literally and *the synonym*"

Comment: You should provide context: ***Idiomatically synonyms***:  http://www.thesaurus.net/idiomatically

Answer (score 4):

I think the word you're looking for is ***[figuratively](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/figuratively)***.

> of the nature of or involving a figure of speech, especially a metaphor; metaphorical and not literal: The word “head” has several figurative senses, as in *“She's the head of the company.”*
>   Synonyms: metaphorical, not literal, symbolic.

Dictionary.com

Comment: "that I be kickin' asses all around, both literally and figuratively" . Is this correct?

Comment: @Quark - yes that sentence makes sense, and uses the term in a normal way. Any English person will understand that you're both beating your opponents in a contest and also physically striking their bottoms with your feet.

Answer (score 2):

both literally and linguistically correct;
There is no real synonym for idiomatically